# Scanner- Not allowing to enter string value after an integer value

Tags: java

The below given program is for reading inputs using scanner. The problem i am facing here is if i try to give an integer value first then it wont allow me to give string value next. it skips automatically to the next line. Any help will be appreciated

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Employee
{
    int empid,salary;
    String empname,designation;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Employee bha=new Employee();
    bha.details();
    bha.display();

    }

    void details()
    {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the empid");
    empid=s.nextInt();//i'm am able to give the value here
    System.out.println("enter the employee name");
    empname=s.nextLine();// automatically skips to the next line(unable to give value)
    System.out.println("enter the employee designation");
    designation=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter the employee salary");
    salary=s.nextInt();
    }
    void display()
    {
    System.out.println("the employee id is"+empid);
    System.out.println("the employee name is"+empname);
    System.out.println("the employee designation 

is"+designation);
    System.out.println("the employee salary is"+salary);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
    System.out.println("enter the empid");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    empid = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
    System.out.println("enter the employee name");
    empname = s.next();
    System.out.println("enter the employee designation");
    designation = s.next();
    System.out.println("enter the employee salary");
    salary = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
```